# SQL Update query using select statement

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to update a column in a table where the another column matches and selecting the top 1 for that column as the value to update.
Hard to explain, but this is what I wrote:

```
UPDATE CameraSpecifications AS a
SET a.Variant = (
SELECT TOP 1 GTIN
FROM CameraSpecifcations 
WHERE b.ModelGroup = a.ModelGroup )
```

Hopefully that explains what I am trying to do.
I have a select statement that might also help:

```
SELECT 
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 b.GTIN
        FROM CameraSpecifications AS b
        WHERE b.ModelGroup = a.ModelGroup
    ) AS Gtin,
    a.ModelGroup, 
    COUNT(a.ModelGroup)
FROM CameraSpecifications AS a
GROUP BY a.ModelGroup
```

Comment: why don't use MERGE statment

Comment: I attempted an answer below but note that your use of `TOP 1` without an ordering makes no sense.  You need to tell us how you want to order things.

Comment: The order doesn't matter, but I adapted it to work with my table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try doing an update join from `CameraSpecifications` to a CTE which finds the top `GTIN` value for each model group.  Note carefully that I use an `ORDER BY` clause in `ROW_NUMBER`.  It makes no sense to use `TOP 1` without `ORDER BY`, so you should at some point update your question and mention `TOP 1` with regard to a certain column.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ModelGroup, GTIN,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ModelGroup ORDER BY some_col) rn
    FROM CameraSpecifications
)

UPDATE cs
SET Variant = t.GTIN
FROM CameraSpecifcations cs
INNER JOIN cte t
    ON cs.ModelGroup = t.ModelGroup
WHERE
    t.rn = 1;
```